# How to play a sound when my bluetooth device is detected

Tags: python, pygame

Started with python programming this morning and wanted to make a simple application that sniffs my phone's Bluetooth when I am around and play a song. This app continues to search for my bluetooth every 27 seconds. If I am still around, it will continue playing but I leave or switch off my bluetooth, I want it to stop the song. I have the following code, everything works fine but I get an error that stops the execution if there is no bluetooth device detected and when I leave or switch off my device, the song continues to play. Please help.

```
import socket
import mmap
from bluetooth import *
import msvcrt
import bluetooth
import pygame, time

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096) #frequency, size, channels, buffersize
pygame.init() #turn all of pygame on.
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
soundObj = pygame.mixer.Sound('sleep.wav')

target_name = "Joelk"
target_address = None

loop = False
isHome = False
playing = False

print("Press Esc to end....")
while loop == False:
    print("Perfoming Enquire")

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        if ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27:
            break
   nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names = True)
print ("found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices))

if 0 == len(nearby_devices):
    print("There is no device nearby")
else:
    print("There is a device")
    for name, addr in nearby_devices:
        print (" %s - %s" % (addr, name))
        if "Joelk" == addr:
            isHome = True

    if(isHome == True):
        if(playing == True):
            print("Playing")
        else:
            soundObj.play()
            playing = True
    else:
        isHome = False
        soundObj.stop()
        print("Not Playing")
```

Comment: Please format your code and tell us the full error message.

Comment: There is an indentation error in the code right now. Please correct this.

Comment: Also this code is not searching every 27 seconds. The literal 27 in that code has a completely different meaning. If you use Pygame anyway I'd use that library for detecting key presses instead of windows specific stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `is_home` to `False` within the main loop.  The only assignment to `False` happens in an `else` branch that is only executed iff `is_home` was `False` anyway so this statement has no effect.

It has to be set to false if no suitable bluetooth device is detected. This can be done with the help of `break` and an `else` clause on the `for` loop over the detected devices.

Without all the unnecessary imports, without star imports, without unnecessary names, without unnecessary parenthesis and comparisons to `bool` literals, and untested:

```
import pygame
from bluetooth import discover_devices


def main():
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
    pygame.init()
    _display = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400))
    sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('sleep.wav')

    is_home = False
    print('Press Esc to end....')
    while True:
        print('Performing Enquire')

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                break

        nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
        print('found {0} devices'.format(len(nearby_devices)))
        if nearby_devices:
            for address, name in nearby_devices:
                print(' {0} - {1}'.format(address, name))
                if name == 'Joelk':
                    is_home = True
                    break
            else:
                is_home = False

            if is_home:
                if sound.get_num_channels() > 0:
                    print('Playing')
                else:
                    sound.play()
            else:
                sound.stop()
                print('Not Playing')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `playing` flag was replaced by querying the `Sound` object on how many channels it is currently playing.  If you wand the sound playing in a gapless loop you should have a look at the optional arguments of the `play()` method regarding looping the sound.

Comment: BlackJack, you are a genius. It's working like a charm. You made a small mistake on the line with if name == 'Joelk':. instead of name, you were supposed to put address because the name's value is the mac address

Comment: When the `name`'s value is the mac _address_ and the `address` holds something that looks like a _name_ (`'Joelk'`) then maybe you got the variable names mixed up yourself a little. ;-) Anyway I'm correcting this in the code above.